# Can I use Functions as data for Column?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I would like to create a table, which contains formulas. These formulas will be passed some id, based on which I would like them to make a SELECT query on a particular table, compute a DOUBLE PRECISION value from query results and return the value (the underlying query is always the same, but the way those functions process the values is different).

These functions will be predefined, they do not have to be anonimous.

Two questions here:

- is this kind of function possible with plpgsql?
- how do I create such a table? Which kind of data does a column have to contain for me to be able to put functions there?

**UPD**

https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/plpgsql-statements?lang=en I found a solution like `EXECUTE <string> USING <parameters>`, so the formula could be stored as a VARCHAR and there can be only one Function, which accepts a VARCHAR as a formula.

If it works, i'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Which dialect of SQL are you using? IIRC there is no `USING` in postges's `EXECUTE`

Comment: @wildplasser `USING` does exist in `plpgsql`  form of `EXECUTE`, which is what @winwin is talking about.

Comment: No you cannot have a function that does what you want as a column. There are generated columns, but they only work with the values in a row. To do what you want you will need to create a trigger function and a trigger that calls on the table in question.

Answer (score 0):

Such a table is called a view:

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS
SELECT id,
       column1,
       myfunc1(id) AS column2,
       myfunc2(id) AS column3
FROM mytable;
```